# How can I make all links on a page trigger an Action in addition to directing the user's browser to the destination url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an application that creates user `notifications` when various things happen within the application.

Each `notification` contains a `link` that is generated upon creation of the `notification` that directs the user to the part of the application the `notification` intends to draw attention.

This `link` can be to anywhere on the site.

**Upon creation, a `notification` is marked as `unread = true`, when a user clicks the `link` I want to take the user to the proper location, but also fire an action that will set the `notification` to `unread = false`.**

How can I accomplish this?  Is there a way I can filter all links on a page to first be redirected to an action that sets the notification to `unread = false` then takes them to the url?  I'm not exactly sure where to start here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do an Ajax call in onclick of the link

```
$("a").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
     url: "url_to_make_notification_read",
     data: notification_id;
  });
});
```

**Edit: another solution (perhaps better)**

Or perhaps you do not really need an extra Ajax Call at all. If I understand your question properly, I believe you have an action like:

```
public ActionResult VisitNotification(int notificationId){
     // Do things
     return View("whatever");
}
```

Just change it to

```
public ActionResult VisitNotification(int notificationId){
     // Do things
     var notification = Repository.GetNotification(notificationId);
     notification.unread = false;
     Repository.Save();
     return View("whatever");
}
```

Comment: @Ecnalyr: Not perfect actually. You still need some work to make it work. I thought u can do that. :)

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll figure it out.  Just needed to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: @Ecnalyr: I figured out another solution to ur problem just after my last comment, but did not have much time then. Please check the edit.

Comment: That would work if the links given for each notification were uniform and always pointed to an action and then forwarded to the view -- but each notification just has a link to some page somewhere and I needed to fire a separate action simultaneously.  I could have done something where I filter every link through an action that brought with it the destination link, but I liked the AJAX solution better.

Answer (score 0):

Or you cuold be old-fashioned and use @Html.ActionLink to generate a link to a controller action of your choice and in that method set your value and return the View the user is supposed to end up at.